# Specific Squawk Codes Information

Tags: squawk-codes

First time poster.
Can anyone tell me please what these 3 codes mean in simple language.
3462
2042
2747

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Nothing***

The only squawk codes that have [meaning are 1200, 7000, 7700, 7600, 7500](https://pilotinstitute.com/squawk-codes-list/), [4000](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap5_section_2.html), [2000](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/what-is-transponder-code-2000-actually-used-for) and [1000](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/61587/when-is-squawk-1000-assigned-in-usa) The other codes are simply assigned to aircraft for a given flight in a given sector.

Comment: Cheers and thanks

Comment: 1201, 1202, 1205, 1206, 1234, 1277, 7777... there are a lot more codes with specific meaning, at least in the USA... https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1040351

Answer (score 6):

As @Dave pointed out, there are very few squawk codes which have the same meaning across all countries in the world. So at the very least we would need to know where in the world these codes were assigned.

If these codes were assigned in the [usa](/questions/tagged/usa), then I would say the following:

The codes you reference are in the 2000, 2700, and 3400 blocks. According to [FAA JO 7110.66, *National Beacon Code Allocation Plan*,](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1040351) each one of those blocks is an "External ARTCC code block." In other words, these are code blocks which the Air Route Traffic Control Center computer draws from when assigning a code to an aircraft whose filed route will take it *outside* of that Center's airspace.

The NBCAP document includes a list of which blocks are assigned to which facility. For example, you can see that the 3400 block is used by ZAN (Anchorage Center), ZBW (Boston Center), ZFW (Fort Worth Center), and ZID (Indianapolis Center) for external departures; it is also used by ZJX (Jacksonville Center) for internal departures.

For the most part squawk codes are assigned randomly when necessary. But some facilities may take certain of their internal squawk codes and permanently assign them to specific "frequent flyer" aircraft that are based in the area, such as medevac helicopters or flight school trainers. So for example the code `0261` may be assigned to "Flight School 1" and `0262` may be assigned to "Flight School 2," and those codes have been removed from the pool that the computer draws on when assigning codes to other flights. These types of code assignments are unlikely to use the codes you asked about.

Comment: I did not know (until it came up in casual conversation with an ATC) that an aerobatic trainer based near my home airport had its own unique squawk code assigned which had all of the rate-of-climb/descent warnings disabled.